# Jquery typahead autocomplete - Pass value to hidden field

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

so I've been searching for hours and tried countless examples to pass back a value to a hidden field once the autocomplete suggestion is selected with no luck.

Can some one please help me out the following is my code. I need to pass back lat_lng value to the hidden field once a autocomplete suggestion is selected.

```
 // this is the typahead function
 $('.typeahead').typeahead({
hint: true,
highlight: true,
minLength: 3,
limit: 2
}, 
{ 
templates: {
    header: '<h3 class="dropdown_ac_div">Cities</h3>'
},
source: function(q, cb) {
    return $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        url: url_proto +'//mydomain.com/autocomplete.php?q=' + q,
        chache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            var result=[];
          $(data).each(function(index,val){

            if (val.city_data.type=='city'){ 
                 $('#hidden-input').val(val.city_data.name);
              result.push({
                value: val.city_data.name +"*"+ val.city_data.lat_lng,

              });

            }
            return  cb(result);       
          });
        }
    });
}
});
```

And this is the html input field

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden-input" />
```

Comment: Are you sure that your ajax call is succeeded that and you right value in callback? Also make sure that you passing your if check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to populate the hidden field. Hopefully this will help somebody. The following is the solution.

```
// I added a var before $('.typeahead') and a key: about halfway down

var typaheadvar=$('.typeahead').typeahead({
hint: true,
highlight: true,
minLength: 3,
limit: 2
}, 
{ 
templates: {
    header: '<h3 class="dropdown_ac_div">Cities</h3>'
},
source: function(q, cb) {
    return $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        url: url_proto +'//mydomain.com/autocomplete.php?q=' + q,
        chache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            var result=[];
          $(data).each(function(index,val){

            if (val.city_data.type=='city'){ 
              result.push({
                value: val.city_data.name,
                key: val.city_data.lat_lng, // this key contains lat_lng for hidden input field
              });
            }
             return  cb(result);   
          });
        }
    });
}
});
```

and then.

```
    // now to pass back value of selected suggestion to hidden field
     typaheadvar.on('typeahead:selected', function($e, datum) {  //     suggestion selected
      $('#hidden-input').val(datum['key']); // now to populate hidden value
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything is OK with your ajax callback and `if` check then you could try to use vanila js if jQuery value setting doesn't work for `hidden` input for some reason:

```
document.getElementById("hidden-input").value = val.city_data.name;
```